# How to preset a filename in OPENFILENAMEW

Tags: winapi

I want to save some data from my program, and I'm trying to give the user a dialog where he can chose where and under what filename he wants the data saved.

Additionally, I want to preset a filename, so that the user gets a suggestion for the filename he might want, if he likes it he can simply click "save" in the dialog, and if not he can overwrite the preset.

I've found hundreds of examples of how to initialize an `OPENFILENAMEW`, but not a single one that presets a filename, and my own attempts to do that don't work.

The filename I would like to preset there is part of the data and exists as a `wstring`, so for easier understanding I'll define one here.

Leaving away the other parts which I did get to work, it boils down to:

```
wstring MyFileName = L"PresetFileName";

OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH];
ZeroMemory(&szFileName, sizeof(szFileName));
ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
```

Converting from `wstring` to `WCHAR`, I just can't get that right. And for all I have seen in countless examples I looked up on the web, similar questions are mostly answered with "you can't convert from wstring to WCHAR", yet just about any text editor I know of has a preset filename in the "save as" dialog (but maybe doesn't use `wstring`).

So, how do I get `MyFileName` into `szFileName` without shortening the size of `szFileName`?

Comment: `StringCchCopy(szFileName, MAX_PATH, MyFileName.c_str())`

Comment: Oh boy, THAT easy? Thanks man.

Comment: You should not be using this API these days. Use IFileDialog now.

Answer (score 0):

As @JonathanPotter answered, use [StringCchCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strsafe/nf-strsafe-stringcchcopyw) to copy one string to another.

[It may be worth noting the conversion between multibyte characters and wide characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-convert-system-string-to-wchar-t-star-or-char-star?view=msvc-170#example).